# Remove block of lines from file depending on presence of string in preceding line, then later another

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a 25-line file that looks like:
`cat -n oz`

`1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k'`
 `2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736`
 `3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409`
 `4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'`
 `5  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677`
 `6  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432`
 `7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'`
 `8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665`
 `9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710`
`10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849`
`11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'`
`12  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 603 tim=4217919229470`
`13  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919229647`
`14  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185`
`15  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919230330`
`16  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 758 tim=4217919231107`
`17  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919231222`
`18  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1635 tim=4217919232874`
`19  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'`
`20  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665`
`21  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710`
`22  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'`
`23  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185`
`24  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919230330`
`25  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 758 tim=4217919231107`

that I want to transform into ("cat -n" of same file once processed):
 `1  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k'`
 `2  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736`
 `3  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409`
 `4  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'`
 `5  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677`
 `6  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432`
 `7  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'`
 `8  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665`
 `9  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710`
`10  WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849`
`11  PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'`
`12  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665`
`13  WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710`

Algorithm is:
o does first line contain (will always start with "PARS...") "dep=1" ?,
o if yes, I keep reading without outputting anything till next "PARS...",
o if contains "dep=0", I display it, with those that follow, till next "PARS...",
o then same check again, ... etc.

How easily can it be done ? Using simple shell command (cat etc.) maybe ? But my file is fairly big...
Thanks a lot.
Seb

Comment: Please, prepend the sample data (and the missing expected output and work done when posting them) with 4 spaces for better readability. Also, you should decide if you want the lines _n_ to _nn_ or content based filtering. Thanks. Oh, _How easily can it be done_ I'd use awk or sed for it, depending. Add those tags, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like:

```
awk '/^PARSING IN CURSOR/{ t = match($0, "dep=1")} !t' input
```

Each time the line of input matches `PARSING IN CURSOR`, check to see if the line matches the string `dep=1` and set `t` accordingly.  The `!t` causes the line to be output if `dep=1` was not in the header.  If `dep=1` was in the header, then `!t` is false and no output is generated.

eg:

```
$ cat input
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 603 tim=4217919229470
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919229647
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919230330
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 758 tim=4217919231107
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919231222
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1635 tim=4217919232874
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=1 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 521 tim=4217919230185
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 0 tim=4217919230330
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 758 tim=4217919231107
$ awk '/^PARSING IN CURSOR/{ t = match($0, "dep=1")} !t' input
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919222030  sqlid='ftf4q8xj38z7k'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919224736
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 655 tim=4217919225409
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919225606  sqlid='9fufagwmu041b'
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919225677
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 736 tim=4217919226432
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
WAIT #1404991: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919228849
PARSING IN CURSOR #140499 dep=0 tim=4217919226577  sqlid='bzdm0nbr7c036'
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 1 tim=4217919226665
WAIT #1404990: nam='SQL*Net message' ela= 2027 tim=4217919228710
```